# Date value is missing after onblur

Tags: javascript, jsp, datepicker

Currently the date value is pass from another page by using parent.document.form but the value is disappear when onblur on it. How to make date value not disappear when onblur on it ?

DEMO : https://test.e-cover.com.my/pib/test/test.jsp

1) click on Get Date button.
2) onblur the text field.

### Jsp A

```
 <div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon">
     <i class="icon wb-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </span>
   <input type="text" name="DOB" id="DOB" value="" class="form-control tt-
 input brdr1" data-plugin="datepicker" maxlength="10">
 </div>
 <br/>

 <input type="button" value="GET DATE" onclick="fnEnable()">
```

### script

```
 function fnEnable()
 {
    document.checkClientID.action = "test2.jsp";
    document.checkClientID.submit();
 }
```

### jsp B

```
 <BODY>
 <script>
    parent.document.mainform.DOB.value ="01-01-1990";
 </script>
 </BODY>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of jsp B `script` tag try:

```
  var datepicker = $(parent.document.mainform.DOB).data('datepicker');
  datepicker.setDate(new Date("01-01-1990"));
```

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setdate

I am not sure if it's good way to get/send your data, have you tried [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)?

Comment: hmm .. it's not working. cannot read property setDate... sorry im not using ajax..